# How Do I Create a Complex Index?

Tags: ignite

I have an SQL as follows:

SELECT * FROM AlarmRecord  WHERE (originSystemName =?) and nativeMeDn in (?)  ORDER BY LATESTOCCURUTC DESC LIMIT 20

How to create a combined index of the three fields (originSystemName, nativeMeDn, and LATESTOCCURUTC)?

```
@QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", order = 1)})
private String nativeMeDn;

@QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", order = 2)})
private String originSystemName;

@QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", descending = true, order = 3)})
private long latestOccurUtc;
```

I thought it was right, but it doesn't seem to be.

Please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `index = true` for all the fields, as well as the `order` value, should be started from 0 instead of 1:

```
@QuerySqlField(index = true, orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", order = 0)})
private String nativeMeDn;

@QuerySqlField(index = true, orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", order = 1)})
private String originSystemName;

@QuerySqlField(index = true, orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "group_idx", descending = true, order = 2)})
private long latestOccurUtc;
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/ignite-2.14/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/model/Person.java).